# How do I add a thumbnail for users to select a satellite view?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am very new to mapbox and leaflet. I am trying to extend the [basic mapbox example here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) to let a user click on a small thumbnail satellite image that will take them to the satellite view. I have been through the examples of both mapbox and leaflet but see no way to do it. Is it possible? Something how google maps does with the satellite view in the lower left hand corner:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY/@40.6971494,-74.2598655,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127753!4d-74.0059728?hl=en-US

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>A simple map</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYndhZGFtc29uIiwiYSI6ImNqajZhNm1idDFzMjIza3A2Y3ZmdDV6YWYifQ.9NhptR7a9D0hzWXR51y_9w';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([40, -74.50], 9);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Though this example is mapbox js I really don't care if it is mapbox gl or js. Can be either. ok thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mapbox static api to get a preview of the satellite image:

```html
<img src="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/-74.50000,40.00000,9.0,0,0/300x300?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYndhZGFtc29uIiwiYSI6ImNqajZhNm1idDFzMjIza3A2Y3ZmdDV6YWYifQ.9NhptR7a9D0hzWXR51y_9w"/>
```

[ https://www.mapbox.com/help/static-api-playground/ ]

**Update**:

You can use the [`mapbox/geo-viewport`](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-viewport) library to calculate centerpoint and zoom for preview, and `render` event to update preview:

```
map.on('render', function() {
  setMapPreview()
})

function setMapPreview() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds().toArray()
  bounds = [bounds[0][0], bounds[0][1], bounds[1][0], bounds[1][1]]

  // The size of the desired map.
  var size = [100, 100];

  // Calculate a zoom level and centerpoint for this map.
  var vp = geoViewport.viewport(bounds, size, 0, 24, 512);

  // Construct a static map url
  // https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/
  document.getElementById('preview').src =
    'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/' +
    vp.center.join(',') + ',' + vp.zoom + ',0,0/' +
    size.join('x') + '?' +
    'attribution=false&logo=false&access_token=' + mapboxgl.accessToken;    
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/btv9ogpc/ ]

It's not a problem to add an event click to the preview, and rotate styles:

```
document.getElementById('preview').addEventListener('click', function () {
  map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9')
})
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/xh74rb83 ]

Comment: ok. How do I make put the preview in the bottom corner of the main map?

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks. Is there an easy trick to make it so when the user clicks on the satellite preview it makes that the satellite view the larger view (and the regular map the thumbnail view)?

Comment: @MarissaLevy It's not a problem to add an event `click` to the preview, and rotate styles: https://jsfiddle.net/xh74rb83/

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you would be interested by some [Leaflet plugins for Layer Switching Controls](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls) ([mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js) is built onto Leaflet, so they should be compatible):

- [Leaflet.Basemaps](https://github.com/consbio/Leaflet.Basemaps): (ISC License)

> A tile driven basemaps control for Leaflet.
>
> It allows you to create a user interface control for choosing the basemap used on the map, based on a tile from the underlying tile service.
>
> See the [example](https://consbio.github.io/Leaflet.Basemaps).

With this plugin, you simply specify some constant tile coordinates to be used as "preview":

```
map.addControl(L.control.basemaps({
    basemaps: basemaps, // Array of Tile Layers.
    tileX: 0,  // tile X coordinate
    tileY: 0,  // tile Y coordinate
    tileZ: 1   // tile zoom level
}));
```

- [Leaflet-IconLayers](https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers): (MIT License)

> Leaflet control that displays base layers as small icons ([demo](http://scanex.github.io/Leaflet-IconLayers/examples)).

[image: animated capture of plugin in action]

For this plugin, even though the [documentation](https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers/blob/master/README.md#using-control) uses [different images](https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers/tree/master/examples/icons) sized 80x80 pixels as preview icon, you can very well re-use tiles with specific coordinates, and the plugin will resize them to fit its icons:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 5);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 17,
  attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
});

var layers = [{
  layer: OpenStreetMap_Mapnik,
  title: 'OSM Mapnik',
  icon: 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/0/0.png'
}, {
  layer: OpenTopoMap,
  title: 'OSM Topo',
  icon: 'https://a.tile.opentopomap.org/1/0/0.png' // Re-use a tile
}];

L.control.iconLayers(layers).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers/ea9af769/dist/iconLayers.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ScanEx/Leaflet-IconLayers/ea9af769/dist/iconLayers.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

If you wish you can also use images from mapbox static API as shown in [stdob--'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51351038/5108796).